# Using CURL to download file is having issue

Tags: shell, unix, curl

I am trying to download a file from remote server using curl

```
   curl -u username:password -O https://remoteserver/filename.txt
```

In my case a file filename.txt is getting created but the content of file says virtaul user logged in. It is not downloading the actual file.

I am not sure why this is happening. Any help on why the download is not working.

Comment: probably this is because the page itself is returning this content

Comment: When I tried to paste the URL in browser it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
curl -u username:password -o filedownload.txt -0 https://remoteserver/filename.txt
```

This command with **-o** will copy the contents of `filename.txt` to `filedownload.txt` in the current working directory.